# Expresión Regular para impedir un texto determinado con DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

Con los DataAnnotations de MVC .Net, intento que al momento llenar un campo x no me deje ingresar `00:00`. Hay que tener en cuenta que los campos no los creo yo manualmente, se crean automáticamente con Kendo MVC.

Ya estoy validando el largo de la cadena (siempre tienen una longitud fija de 4). Quiere decir que si el cliente no ingresa algún carácter, automáticamente se llenan con ceros.

Pero necesito que no se permita ingresar (que sea inválida):

> ```
> 00:00
> ```

He mirado alguna documentación sobre las expresiones regulares, pero no logro hacer lo que necesito. Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("02:00",@"^[^(00\:00)]$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) // deberia imprimir "BUENA", pero me imprime "NO PASO"
    Console.Write("BUENA");
else
    Console.Write("NO PASO");
```

---

Como referencia, este es el código de la clase:

```
public partial class CompararCadena : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string ValorAComparar { get; set; }

    public CompararCadena(string ValorAComparar)
    {
        this.ValorAComparar = ValorAComparar;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var dataFormat = (value ?? string.Empty).ToString().Replace("_",string.Empty).Replace(":",string.Empty);
            int data;
            int.TryParse(dataFormat, out data);
            if (dataFormat == this.ValorAComparar || data <= 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Error inesperado {0} ", ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60558/discussion-between-andrezi-and-mariano).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás haciendo, inintencionalmente, demasiadas preguntas diferentes en una (entre pregunta y comentarios). Intentaré responder, al menos superficialmente, a las diferentes posibilidades:

1. ¿Cómo coincidir con cualquier texto excepto `"00:00"`?

   No uses regex.

   ```cs
   if (texto != "00:00")
   {
       //Válido
   }
   ```

   ---
2. ¿Cómo se podría validar con DataAnnotations que no se ingrese `"00:00"`?

   No uses regex. De nuevo, es una comparación de un string como en el caso anterior.
   Hay varias opciones, pero fácilmente se puede usar algo en la línea de:

   ```cs
   public class NameAttribute:ValidationAttribute
   {
       public override bool IsValid(object value)
       {
           return value.ToString != "00:00";
       }
   }
   ```

   ---
3. ¿Cómo sería una expresión regular que valide una hora diferente de `"00:00"`?

   No es lo recomendable. Pero si igual te interesa:

   Para validar utilizando regex, no se busca que sea diferente a un texto, sino que se buscan todos los textos válidos. Es decir, una hora entre `00:01` y `23:59`. Esto sería:

   ```cs
   ^(?:00:(?:0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9])|(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$
   ```

   O validando:

   ```cs
   [RegularExpression(@"^(?:00:(?:0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9])|(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "Ingresa una hora diferente de 00:00")]
   public string Hora { get; set; }
   ```

   ---
4. ¿Está bien la expresión regular `[^(00:00)]`?

   ¡No! Veamos qué significa:

   `[`...`]` - es una clase de caracteres, que coincide **con uno**, y solamente un caracter, dentro de los incluidos en la clase.

   - `^` - niega a la clase. O sea, hace que coincide con un caracter, cualquiera menos los incluidos en la clase.
   - `(00:00)` - son los caracteres excluidos: `(`, ni `0`, ni `0`, ni `:`, ni `:`, ni `0`, ni `0`, ni `)`...
     (-sí, es redundante).

   Es decir, que se podría expresar como `[^0:()]`, y es un regex que coincide con 1 solo caracter, en cualquier posición del texto, que no sea uno de esos 4 caracteres.

   ---
5. Bien, ya entendí que hay mejores alternativas pero, por curiosidad, ¿cómo se puede negar con una expresión regular?

   Negando el resultado del método (es la mejor y más eficiente opción si se debe usar regex).

   ```cs
   Regex horaCero = new Regex(@"^00:00$"); //Se usa ^ y $ para inicio y fin de texto (y que no coincida en el medio)

   if ( !horaCero.isMatch(texto) ) //Método negado con !
   {
       //Válido
   }
   ```

   Y ¿para negar *dentro* del regex?
   Se puede usar una inspección negativa:

   ```cs
   Regex noEsCero = new Regex(@"^(?!00:00$)");
   ```

   Esto coincide con la posición inicial del string, siempre y cuando no esté seguida por "00:00" y el final del string. Pero debería ser la última opción a utilizar dentro de todas las posibles.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si probamos **que sí tenga** el valor y no nos matamos la cabeza con negative look aheads?

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("02:00",@"00\:00",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
    Console.Write("NO PASO");
else
    Console.Write("BUENA");
```

Y de paso te dejo la pagina [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5yEYI3/1) para que jueges con las expresiones regulares.

Comment: esa seria la misma sintaxis para c#, no debo poner antes que  desde el inicio de la cadena

Comment: y para negarlo seria asi [^(00:00)] `string hora = "00:00";
            if(Regex.IsMatch(hora ,@"[^(00:00)]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                Console.Write("Buena");
            else
                Console.Write("Mala");`

Comment: ¿qué sentido tiene usar una expresión regular para algo que se puede comparar con `texto != "00:00"`?  Además, está expresión devolvería "NO PASO" con `02:00:00`